# Android pattern lock/unlock screen programmatically

Tags: android

Part of my app is to lock screen using a certain pattern the user chooses and unlocks it with the same pattern. I wish to use the same android default Pattern lock screen.  I want the user to be able to set up multiple patterns and unlock the screen with these patterns.

Any ways I can do that? Is there some intent or class I can call to do that? Or do I have to develop such mechanisim from scratch? I have no idea where to start with

Heeeelp!
Thank you

Comment: any solution to this bro ?

Answer (score 2):

Lets try below code really helpful

```
Intent settingIntent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
startActivityForResult(settingIntent, 0);
```

many thanks

Comment: How do I get the pattern that the person entered?

Comment: i think you have to design your own i mean you have design custom for your application i think so.

Comment: How to lock device like device automatically lock when call is comes we pick up and disconnect?

Answer (score 0):

You can call lockNow method by `DevicePolicyManager`.

```
public class MobileDeviceAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {


}

ComponentName deviceAdminReceiver = new ComponentName(this, MobileDeviceAdminReceiver.class); // Register BroadcastReceiver in manifest;
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);// admin permission intent
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,deviceAdminReceiver);
```

Or create your custom lock screen that monitoring top activity and block it.

Comment: plz brief more about how to call lockNow. I am getting a SecurityException.